# the quantile to quantile plot for the discrete law

Tags: probability

the quantile to quantile plot works good for the continuous law. But I don't know why it doesn't work for the discrete law, example the law Poisson.

Please help me

Comment: One problem I see with discrete laws is that the quantile are not well defined because there are many ties